# XSL - Modify XML Export to Excel to add Bold Style Dynamically

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I'm trying to modify an XML file using a XSL file to create an Excel spreadsheet - I've got the basics of this working but now need to customise it a bit. The 6th column in the XML file contains a 1 for some records and I would like to modify the output to apply a bold style to any rows where the FlagBold field/6th col equals 1.

Here's my current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="06-06-2017" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 16.0.2"/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnA" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnB" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnC" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnD" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ColumnE" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="FlagBold" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="6">
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="900">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Created: 15-August-2017</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="901">
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="902">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Name</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>ID</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Category</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Number</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Amount</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="904">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Acme Corp Pty Ltd</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>123456</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Category 1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>$456.78</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="905">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Demo Company Pty Ltd</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>987654</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Category 2</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>$789.32</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

In my XSL file I have this style:

```
        <Style ss:ID="MyTitleStyle">
            <Alignment ss:WrapText="0" />
            <Font  ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
```

and I'm processing the rows here:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
    <Row>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL">
            <Cell>
                <xsl:if test="fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA = 1">
                    <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">MyTitleStyle</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>           
                <Data ss:Type="String">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </Data>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:for-each><!-- next column -->
    </Row>
</xsl:for-each><!-- next row -->
```

but I'm not getting any bold style in the .xls spreadsheet file that is created and not sure what I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test in:

```
<xsl:if test="fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA = 1">
```

will never return true from the context of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL">
```

Change it to:

```
<xsl:if test="../fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA = 1">
```